# Input in two words in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where some of the inputs come in two words. I have posted a minimal working example below. When I try to select the first column called "Word" everything is fine. However, when I try to select the second column in my dataframe called "Word word", I get the following error ":1:6: unexpected symbol 1: Word word".

Thus, my question is, how do I write the input$y statement, when the input is in two words?

I have tried to use the paste function, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
library(shiny)

library(ggplot2)


data<-data.frame(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))

names(data)<-c("Word","Word word")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput( inputId="y",label="Dimension",choices=c("Word","Word word")),
                                        plotOutput("plot"))



server<-function(session,input,output){

  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=data, aes_string(y=input$y,x="Word"))+geom_line()
  })



}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error you are receiving is due to having a space in your variable name, when using `aes_string`. Spaces in variable names are discouraged.

To get the plot of `Word word` you would need to do the following:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes_string(y = "`Word word`", x = "Word")) + geom_line()
```

and place `Word word` in tick marks. But this would not match your input string.

For an option, if you ensured your variables used underscores between words, you could do the following:

```
names(data)<-c("Word", "Word_word")
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput( inputId="y",label="Dimension",choices=c("Word" = "Word", "Word word" = "Word_word")),
  plotOutput("plot"))
```

And I would guess this would work as desired. Let me know if I'm missing something, or if this is what you had in mind.